# Change Image CGRectMake Depending on iPad or iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a couple of images views, with frames set with `CGRectMake()`. These images fit the iPhone fine, but once they're viewed on the iPad, they remain the same small size.

Is there a way to change the size of the `CGRectMake` depending upon iPad or iPhone?

Example current code:

```
backgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(3, 3, 55, 55);
```

Comment: Why not use an `autoresizingMask`?

Comment: Not familiar with this. How would I implement it to change for iphone/ipad?

Comment: I guess this depends more on your use case. But assuming you have one .nib for iPhone and iPad, or if no .nib, the initial size of your view controller's view is constant before displaying it (before `- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews` is called) then your images will just stretch proportionately to the iPhone/iPad screen size. Just set `UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleHeight`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    backgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(3, 3, 55, 55);
} else {
    backgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(/* iPad-friendly values here*/);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
// iPad
{

}
else
// iPhone
{

}
```